# Codeigniter 404 page on homepage

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

I have a codeigniter hmvc installation on my server. http://dev.merolist.com

But it shows 404 page.

It is working on my local server fine.

If i put `$config['controller_suffix'] = '_Controller';` then it gives 404 page.

if i remove it. it works.

My default router is `$route['default_controller'] = "Template"`;

class file is:

```
class Template_Controller extends MX_Controller
{
    public function index($page = 'index')
    {       
        $data['title'] = ucfirst($page); // Capitalize the first letter
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $data['view_page'] = $page;
        $this->load->view('template/master', $data);
    }
}
```

.htaccess file is default one.

```
AddDefaultCharset UTF-8

RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$1 [L]
```

Any suggesstions?

Comment: Yeah, remove the suffix if it works.

Comment: i NEED the suffix, since i have 2 many classes with same name! Any suggestion to make it work without removing suffixes?

Comment: What if you add the question mark here: `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]`

Comment: didnt work after adding ? either.

Comment: Can you open any URL when typing the controller name as well? I tried '/template` and '/template_Controller`, but got 404s, so I'm not sure I could help because this is server-related.

Comment: try to use another suffix like _Cont maybe Controller is being used for something else.

Comment: No, i get 404 on typing controller name as well. how to solve server-related? How come it's working on local and not on server? is it a server configuration issue? i could give you full access to ftp if you want to try yourself. thank you

Comment: _Cont also didnt work.

Comment: where is this $config['controller_suffix'] i couldn't find it in condeigniter/application/config/config.php

Comment: Try to use #2 hack in this great article http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/6-codeigniter-hacks-for-the-masters/

Comment: $config['controller_suffix'] is to be added manually so as to use _controller suffix on your controllers.